# extract value from previous df to new df based on column criteria

Tags: python, pandas, merge

extract value from previous df (df1) to new df(df2) based on the corresponding criteria of DATE and symbol in df2 in shorter way.

I usually transform df1 structure use pd.melt, then use pd.merge to merge with df2. I want to do it in shorter way since I have many dfs. any link reference or suggestion? many thanks in advance

df1 =

```
        DATE    a   b   c
0   2006-10-31  100 200 300
1   2006-11-30  10  400 5
2   2006-12-28  50  5   90
```

df2 =

```
        DATE    symbol  desired ouput
0   2006-10-31  a       100
1   2006-11-30  b       400
2   2006-12-28  c       90
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variant on an [indexing lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup), using a reindexing of `df1`:

```
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df2['symbol'])

df2['desired output'] = (
 df1.set_index('DATE')
    .reindex(index=df2['DATE'],
             columns=cols)
    .to_numpy()
)[np.arange(len(df1)), idx]
```

Another approach (probably less efficient) would be to [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and  [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
out = df2.merge(df1.melt('DATE', var_name='symbol', value_name='desired output'))
```

Output:

```
         DATE symbol  desired output
0  2006-10-31      a             100
1  2006-11-30      b             400
2  2006-12-28      c              90
```

Comment: thanks mozway.. the last code is simpler..